# Slick 3.x - Work with foreign entitites

Tags: sql, scala, playframework, slick-3.0

I know that Slick is not ORM, but sometimes we need to resolve some real world cases where ORM works good.

My current case is 1-M and 1-1 relations between different entities.

So my domains looks like

```
case class Entity1(id: Long, child: Option[Child1])
case class Entity2(id: Long, children: Seq[Child2], children2: Seq[Child3])
```

ChildX entities represent different table in database and Slick mapping is created for them.

So here are some questions to find the best practices:

1. What is best way work with this domain in CRUD terms and store
   parent-child relationships?
2. What is the best way to paginate over parent table and load children as well?

Comment: Did you consult the documentation [coming from orm to slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/orm-to-slick.html#relationships)? There you'll find the sentence "This doesn’t fit to Slick’s philosophy of giving you fine-grained control over what you load exactly." ;-)

Comment: @jan0sch, Sure thing I read it and saw this quote :) . But the purpose of my question is to get some best practices techniques on how to organize the different relations between entities in terms of Slick 3.x.

Comment: I tend to solve 1-1 relations using joins (for read) and chained updates (via `andThen`) if they need be. You can also use that for 1-M but I try to avoid nesting models whenever possible. This is unusual at first if coming from orm background but gives you more flexibility in the long run.